# See the event listeners in Flex/Flash builder debug

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Do anyone know how to see the event listeners of any component in the debug mode of the Flex or Flash builder?

Cheers,PK

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightfoward way to enumerate listeners AFAIK.

You can still do what you would usually have to do with methods from the IEventDispatcher interface:

```
package flash.events
{
    public interface IEventDispatcher
    {
        function addEventListener(eventName:String, 
                        listener:Object,
                        useCapture:Boolean=false,
                        priority:Integer=0,
                            useWeakReference:Boolean=false):Boolean;

        function removeEventListener(eventName:String, 
                    listener:Object,
                    useCapture:Boolean=false):Boolean;

        function dispatchEvent(eventObject:Event):Boolean;

        function hasEventListener(eventName:String):Boolean;
        function willTrigger(eventName:String):Boolean;
    }
}
```

Source of the above code: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=16_Event_handling_6.html

Comment: This doesn't address the question?  Also, editing the interface would break the built in player method in playerglobal.swc

Comment: @Nate: yeah, my understanding is that a registered listeners is not meant to be retrieved probably because 1- listeners are not "registered" in a trackable way other then by the address of the method that gets invoked and 2- such methods can be anonymous.

Answer (score -1):

create a variable on the class called:

private var __numListeners:Number=0;

then create a set and get method to edit that variable...
and each time a listener is added or removed it adjusts that var using that method...

```
this.setNumListeners(1); or whatever
```

then it can be accessed through a

```
trace(someObject.getNumListeners())
```

Comment: I'm confused how is this related to the original question?

Comment: if i am not wrong then the question is asked about the debug mode in flash builder and he wants to trace out the event listener added on component. if it's not useful then sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @SWato Singh The original poster wanted a list of event listeners; true.  But nothing in the original question had anything to do w/ trace statements.  I don't understand how enabling / disabling the trace statements could give him the info he wanted.  (Unless he explicitly puts a trace statement in every listener).

Comment: @Flextras, you are correct, that was my original requirement.

Comment: @Anoop sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: -1 this doesn't have anything to do with tracing the events to the console.

Answer (score -1):

There is no quick way to do this without editing all of the components in your app that implement the IEventDispatcher interface.

If the player was open source then you could extend the EventDispatcher class to add trace statements into it, but it isn't.